# Java Calendar Issue

Tags: java, algorithm, oracle, calendar

I made a small program to count days. to count 150 days from May 22nd. But the result is 18th of October. The actual date is 19th October. Can anyone help me find whats wrong with my code.

---

```
Calendar mine = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.MAY,22);
    int month = Calendar.MAY;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=mine.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);i<=mine.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);i++){
    System.out.println("i "+i);

        counter++;
        System.out.println("counter "+counter);
    if(i==mine.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
        month++;
        i=1;

        mine.set(2013, month, i);
        counter++;
        System.out.println("i "+i+" "+mine.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
        if(counter == 150){

        System.out.println("day "+i+ counter +"days"+ "month:"+ mine.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
        break;
        }
    }
        if(counter == 150){

        System.out.println("i "+i+" counter "+ counter +" date:"+mine.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
        break;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Unless you ABSOLUTLY have to use `Calendar`, it would be better to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: oh I thought Calendar is my only option. Thanks. I should try Joda Time.

Comment: Joda Time take into better consideration leap years and seconds and the strangeness around the century boundries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2013, Month.MAY, 22 )
         .plusDays( 150 )
```

## Using java.time

Much easier with the modern [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The [`Month`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) offers a dozen pre-defined objects, one for each month of the year.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2013, Month.MAY, 22 ) ;
LocalDate later = ld.plusDays( 150 );
```

See [this code live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/oCTaIi).

> 2013-10-19

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Appreciate your answer even after long time, but given me good grasp.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `add` function of the `Calendar`

```
Calendar mine = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.MAY,22);
mine.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 150);
System.out.println(mine.getTime());
```

will print

```
Sat Oct 19 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

But the real problem with your code was that, you were incrementing `counter` first and then doing comparison with `150`.

do it like this and it should fix your code

```
if(counter == 150){
   System.out.println("i "+i+" counter "+ counter +date:"+mine.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
   break;
}
counter++;
```

Comment: wow... <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/991778/sanbhat"></a>
thanks. How silly I missed that.

Comment: THANKS sanbhat,, vikingsteve,, MadProgrammer for your valuable help.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use Joda DateTime:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
....
System.out.println(new DateTime("2013-05-22").plusDays(150));
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque correct. Everyone - please see Basil's answer, I'm upvoting it, it should rise to the top.